# How to bind data using custom form controller to view in mvc4

Tags: asp.net, linq, asp.net-mvc-4

mycontroller.cs

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(int searchtext)
    {
        var data = (from pm in db.ProductMasters
                    join shi in db.SuppliersHotelsInfoes
                        on pm.ProductID equals shi.LocHotelID
                    where shi.SearchID == searchtext
                    select pm).ToList().Take(10);
        ViewBag.Data = data;
            return View();
    }
```

am sending viewBag.Data to view

```
 <% try { %>
    <tr><td>
        <% foreach(var item in ViewBag.Data){ %>
        <img alt="" src="<%item. %>" />
            </td><%} %>            <% foreach(var item in ViewBag.Data) { %>
        <td><%: Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => "")%></td>
        <td><%: Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => "")%> </td>
        <td><%: Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => "")%></td>
    </tr>
    <%} }%>
    <%catch(Exception ex){ }%>
</table>
```

Here, how can we take the values from "var item"

Comment: you are not able to acces via item.SomeProperty

Comment: but how can i take the data..? for which will b bind while in runtime..
also i tried with item["ProductId"] but i'm getting compile time error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't used aspx view syntax for a while but I believe you are missing the equals sign.

You currently have this:

```
<img alt="" src="<%item. %>" />
```

instead it should be this

```
<img alt="" src="<%=item. %>" />
```

Notice the `=` before "item"

Take a look here for more info http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/04/06/new-lt-gt-syntax-for-html-encoding-output-in-asp-net-4-and-asp-net-mvc-2.aspx

Also consider using a later version of MVC which supports razor syntax which is much cleaner.

**Edit:**

After your comment I see your issue. You are using the ViewBag which is a dynamic type. Therefore it cannot infer that your `ViewBag.Data` object is a collection of product masters. You have two options:

Option 1 - Don't use the ViewBag, instead use a strongly typed model.

Option 2 - In your view cast your `ViewBag.Data` to the List of Product Masters.

For example:

Instead of

```
<% foreach(var item in ViewBag.Data){ %>
```

Use this

```
<% foreach(var item in (List<ProductMaster>)ViewBag.Data){ %>
```

Comment: thanq so much #robasaurus :-)